# How to load comments without refreshing the page in nodeJs and Ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

The actual challenge that I am facing now is how to load the comment properly. My Ajax is creating the comment but I am struggling to load the comment properly in line with other comments.
what happening now is that the comment loads but it doesn't load properly, I am struggling to load it with the right `ID` in the right place. when it loads, it shows my title and descriptions together and it doesn't load the date.

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <h1>Comment App</h1>

                <form action="/programs/<%= program._id %>/createComment" method="POST" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="name" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="description" id="descriptioncomment" class="form-control" placeholder="comment"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" id="post-comment" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <ul id="commentList" class="list-group">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="content-item" id="comments">
            <div class="row"  id="comment-lists" >
                <div class="col-sm-10" >
                    <h3 id="comments-count" ><%= program.programcomments.length%> </h3>
                    <% program.programcomments.forEach(comments=> { %>
                        <div class="media"  >
                            
                            <div class="media-body" >
                                <h4 class="media-heading" id="lists"  ><%= comments.name %></h4>
                                <p id="lists" ><%=comments.description %></p>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline media-detail pull-left" id="lists">
                                    <li id="lists"><i class="fa fa-calendar" ></i><%= moment(comments.createdAt).format('llll') %></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <% });%>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>

$('#post-comment').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
            
        $.ajax({
            url : "/programs/<%= program._id %>/createComment",
            method : 'POST',
            data : {
                name : $('#username').val(),
                description : $('#descriptioncomment').val()
            },
            success : function(result ) {
                $('.form-control').each(function () {
                    let comments = this.value;
                    $('#comment-lists').append($('#lists').text(comments)) 
                    document.getElementById('comments-count').innerHTML++
                    
                });
                $("#username").val('');
                $("textarea#descriptioncomment.form-control").val('');
            }
        }); 
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same ids for **mutliple** elements so first remove them and use **class**. Then , you can generate entire `media` div inside success function of ajax with the value of inputs and then append them inside your `comment-lists` div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#post-comment').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();


  /*$.ajax({
    url: "/programs/<%= program._id %>/createComment",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      name: $('#username').val(),
      description: $('#descriptioncomment').val()
    },
    success: function(result) {*/
  //append new div .. with username & desc
  $('#comment-lists').append(`<div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading">${$('#username').val()}</h4>
          <p class="lists">${$('#descriptioncomment').val()}</p>
          <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline media-detail pull-left lists">
            <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>${moment(new Date()).format('llll') }</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>`)
  $("#comments-count").text(parseInt($("#comments-count").text()) + 1) //updated total
  //then emtpy
  $("#username").val('');
  $("textarea#descriptioncomment.form-control").val('');
  /*}
   });*/


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <h1>Comment App</h1>

      <form action="/programs/<%= program._id %>/createComment" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input name="name" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="description" id="descriptioncomment" class="form-control" placeholder="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" id="post-comment" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul id="commentList" class="list-group">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="content-item" id="comments">

  <div class="row" id="comment-lists">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <h3 id="comments-count">2</h3>
      <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading">Abc</h4>
          <p class="lists">Descp xyz</p>
          <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline media-detail pull-left lists">
            <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>23-2-2022</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="media">

        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading lists">Abc</h4>
          <p class="lists">Descp xyz</p>
          <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline media-detail pull-left lists">
            <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>23-2-2022</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code worked, thanks again, i really appreciate the help @Swati